# Apache 2.2 and Apache 2.4 .htaccess rewrite rules are interpreted different?

Tags: apache

I have a VPS server running Apache 2.2 I want migrate to Apache 2.4 BUT when I Activate Apache 2.4 as the default Apache seems .htaccess are no more interpreted.

Apche 2.4 Disable the support of .htacess by default but also if I set `AllowOverride All` seems .htaccess also of Wordpress are not working... so the question is:

How can I understand where the issue is?
Mod rewrite is activated.
Maybe can be the content of the .htaccess no more valid for Apache 2.4 or the issue can be else where... how I can understand where the issue is?

Any help will be apreciated, sorry if you do not find all necessary info you need here, please... if I miss something let me know... I will try to integrate.
Is a quite difficoult issue to fix for me this Apache issue.

Thanks.

Seems in Apache log I have:

[proxy_fcgi:error] AH01071 Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'

Comment: Please post some of the `<VirtualHost>` config where `AllowOverride` is specified. If the .htaccess was parsed but with an error (for example it included a removed or deprecated syntax) Apache would send a 500 error.

Comment: Umh I AM using Webuzo Panel so when I AM on Apache config file i set 'AllowOverride' to All but not work. In my <VirtualHost> I never set AllowOverride I want set for all domain and all Apache config...

Comment: If you're working through a control panel, you may need to contact support staff with your VPS hosting service.

Comment: My hosting does not provide support and I AM trying to investigate the issue with Webuzo Team but for now no solution. MAybe I will find with time what is the issue. Thanks.